# Reach to specific folder without knowing the full path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to find sub-folder inside the main folder.

Example like I have a folder called `build` and inside build there are sub-folders as an example `XYZ`, Inside `XYZ` there are other sub-folders like `ZYX`, Inside it there are other folders. full path like : `build\XYZ\ZYX\ABC`.

I want to go to `ABC` but, I don't have a path to reach it. How to find sub-folder and go to it in PowerShell script.
Will `Get-childItem` work? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all directories and use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to exclude all folder which has sub directories:

```
Get-ChildItem 'your_path_to_build' -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object { ![IO.Directory]::GetDirectories($_.FullName) }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer man. I understood half but I don't get where-object and later on. So, Get-childItem C:\CICD\TestCICD -Recurse -Directory | This is my half command. and in TestCICD I have a hierarchy of sub folder as C:\CICD\TestCICD\mvadaria\mv\mv1\mv2. I am finding mv2. Can you write commands according to this example. Thanks again

Comment: The Get-ChildItem with the parameters returns you four folders: mvadaria, mv, mv1 and mv2. Then the Where-Object cmdlet filters all folders which doesn't have a subfolder. Thus only mv2 is returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-Directory` switch and search recursively using below command:

```
Get-ChildItem *ABC* -Recurse -Directory
```

Where *ABC * is the part of the name of the folder that you are trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit long winded but I guess you are trying to first find out the longest path (deepest in the hierarchy) to cd to it, so maybe something like this:

```
Set-Location (Get-ChildItem 'c:\CICDTestCICD' -Recurse -Directory |% { 
               [PSCustomObject]@{Path=$_.FullName; 
                                 Depth=($_.fullname.split('\')).count 
                                } 
                                                                     } | 
             sort Depth -Descending | select -first 1
            ).path
```

The idea is that:

- you split full path name using '\' as a separator for each directory;
- create a PSCustomObject to hold the Full Path and Depth of Directory for each
- Sort by the depth and select the deepest path in the hierarchy
- Print the full path and change directory to that